# How to rename a file with a unique file name python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, rename

I'm trying to save a .pdf file with a unique name grabbed from an sqlite database using python code.

For example, I have a file named "boringfile.pdf" but need to rename this file to a unique employee name, "max_steel.pdf"

I've looked at `os.rename`, `os.join`, `uuid`, `pdfrw`, and `reportlabs` for a solution.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

For further clarification, the database is created using sqlite3 using python 3.6.  The example database would look similar to this:

```
employee_id     first_name    last_name
123456          Frank         Sinatra
738323          Johnny        Cash
842028          Bon           Jovi
```

So let's say I just created Bon Jovi's employee in-processing paperwork by extracting data from the database and inputting it into my report.  My report currently has the label "boringfile.pdf" but I need it to read "bon_jovi.pdf" when the completed file is saved.

Comment: `os.rename('boringfile.pdf','max_steel.pdf')` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the response.  That approach would work if I wanted to manually rename each file.  What I need to do, and I should have made more clear in my question, is have the code automatically populate the file name based on the employee profile information inside the file.

Comment: Ok, what's in the `sqlite` database? Can you read it with Python? How do you know which name needs to be given to a specific file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I made an edit to my question which I hope answers your questions.

Comment: So you want to rename `boringfile.pdf` as `bon_jovi.pdf` but you only know the `id` is 842028?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are using SQLite to create a CSV file and then parse the CSV file. That seems somewhat superfluous. You could do it directly like this (no error checking, just the concept):

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to database
db = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')

# Extract person's full name
sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE last_name=? OR first_name=? OR employee_id=?"
c = db.cursor()
data = c.execute(sql, ('Jovi','Bon','842028'))

# Rename PDF
for row in c:
    print('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    PDFname = row[1] + '_' + row[0] + '.pdf'

os.rename('boringfile.pdf', PDFname)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Marked best answer since it directly answers the question.  The purpose of the .csv is so I can auto-populate fillable pdf forms.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after consulting various websites and calling a few people.  After creating a `sqlite3` database I call the information I want and convert it into a one line `.csv`.  I use `csv.reader` to read the data and use `os.rename` to generate the unique name, very similar to Mark's suggestion above.

```
def dataexport(self, *args, **kwargs):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE last_name=? OR first_name=? OR employee_id=?"
    data = c.execute(sql, (self.last_se.get(), self.first_se.get(),
                           self.employeeid_se.get(), )) #this part is meant to grab 
                           #the user input from a gui I made to make form filling 
                           #simple
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)

def renamefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
    mycsv = csv.reader(open('output.csv'))
    for row in mycsv:
        employee_id = row[0]
        first_name = row[1]
        last_name = row[2]

    os.rename('boringfile.pdf', first_name + '_' + last_name + '.pdf')
```

**output.csv**

After running the first function, the .csv file should be one line:

`842028, Bon, Jovi`